# This portlet has been undeployed. Please redeploy it or remove it from the page.

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have 7 portlets on one page.When i minimize all couple of times and then maximize just one,and then do some action on that portlet this message appear:
This portlet has been undeployed. Please redeploy it or remove it from the page.
Any solutions ?

Comment: which version do you use? Does it happen with any portlets, or with specific ones?

Comment: 6.1.2 CE,on any portlet